# Bootstrap 3.3.4 not displaying dropdown items in IE 11

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am having an issue with the Bootstrap menu dropdown in IE browser... as you can see from the image attached below, all the items in dropdown in IE are not showing? You can view the code in our live sites
http://www.albaloo.com/products_list/quick_search

Bare in mind that this is just our soft launch. Please help.

[Dropdown Items not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbaCV.jpg)

PS: My English sucks... so yeah.

Comment: Could you show your code, please? Copy-pasted rather than screenshot.

Comment: Your Javascript is throwing errors, you will probably have luck if you fix them first.

Comment: Hi @AgataB, I have provided a URL above, let me know if you can't find it. THanks.

Comment: Hi @DavidG, Yeah this is one of problem as well, will bring this out in another post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please put following code on your HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Hope it will be OK.

if previous solution is not work then you can add two script on your HTML:

```
<script src="http://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="http://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Hi @Abul Kashem Shamim, thank you for your swift reply. I have inserted Meta and both JS accordingly but to no avail.